# Unable to execute DTS in sql server 2008 from dtexec

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, dts

I'm trying to execute a **DTS** from sqlserver 2008 R2 (Windows Server 2008 Standard) from stored procedure `xp_cmdshell`.

But getting below error:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 10.50.4000.0
>   for 64-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> NULL Started:  2:22:13 PM Error: 2015-06-23 14:22:13.85
>   Code: 0xC0011007    Source: {819137B9-D66C-460F-BFE6-BD6814802AEA}
>
> Description: Unable to load the package as XML because of package does
>   not have a valid XML format. A specific XML parser error will be
>   posted. End Error Error: 2015-06-23 14:22:13.85    Code: 0xC0011002
>
> Source: {819137B9-D66C-460F-BFE6-BD6814802AEA}     Description: Failed
>   to open package file "d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\package.dtsx;EXE" due to error 0x800C0006 "The
>   system cannot locate the object specified.".  This happens when
>   loading a package and the file cannot be opened  or loaded correctly
>   into the XML document. This can be the result of either providing an
>   incorrect file name was specified when calling LoadPackage or the XML
>   file was specified and has an incorrect format. End Error Could not
>   load package "d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\package.dtsx;EXE" because of error 0xC0011002.
>
> Description: Failed to open package file "d:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\package.dtsx;EXE" due to error 0x800C0006 "The
>   system cannot locate the object specified.".  This happens when
>   loading a package and the file cannot be opened or  loaded correctly
>   into the XML document. This can be the result of either providing an
>   incorrect file name was specified when calling LoadPackage or the XML
>   file was specified and has an incorrect format. Source:
>   {819137B9-D66C-460F-BFE6-BD6814802AEA} Started:  2:22:13 PM Finished:
>   2:22:13 PM Elapsed:  0.016 seconds NULL

But when using same command and same DTS on different Windows server 2008, it works fine.

Comment: Hi! Did you use the double quotes around your path?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check

1. The file path of "dtexec" file and its version.
2. Is the .dtsx file present in the DB server? Check the file path of the .dtsx file that you mentioned in your code.
3. Check the configuration file path of this dtsx file and whether you passed in the right values for the parameters defined in.

Comment: You might also check to see if it's a valid XML file.